# String substring or splitter - sorting data inserted from command line argument

Tags: java

I'm trying to get input from command line argument and sorting them according to their type. e.g. in cmd if user types

```
java myprog From:email@my.com To:email@your.com Body:this is message
```

I've achieved "from" and "to" sorted using substring
i.e

```
    x = args.length;
     for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if (args[i].startsWith("From:")) {
                from = args[i].substring(5);
            } else if(args[i].startsWith("To:")) {
                to = args[i].substring(3);
            } else if (args[i].startsWith("Body:")) { 
                body = args[i].substring(5);    // **I'm stuck here**
        }
    }
```

This is what I tried and it works good except for body. Because it gives output "thisismessage" without space.

I tried splitting them as well. But couldn't work out.

What shall I try?

I'm not expected to change command line argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only expect the output of body to simply be: "this", so not sure why it is "thisismessage".  But, perhaps your program this "is" and "message" are separate arguments.  Maybe your last else if statement could be something like:

```
else if (args[i].startsWith("Body:")) { 
    body = args[i].substring(5);    // **I'm stuck here**
    while(i < x) {
        i++;
        body += " " + args[i];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your body message has spaces in it, so it will appear as multiple arguments.  To pass an argument with spaces in it, surround it with quotes ie

```
java myprog From:email@my.com To:email@your.com "Body:this is message"
```

Comment: I'm not supposed to change the command line argument. That's what making it more complex. I should've mentioned this in question. Sorry

Comment: Then if you know that the body argument will be last, you can append any other arguments to the body text by putting this at the end of your if-else statement: else { body = body + " " + args[i] }

Answer (score 0):

You know exactly what's the pattern and the order of the arguments. Your `for` loop is redundant, you can do:

```
String from = ars[0].substring(5);
String to   = args[1].substring(3);
String body = args[2].substring(5);
```

You should wrap the last argument with `"` in order to tell that it's one argument.

Comment: I'm not supposed to change the command line argument. That's what making it more complex.

Comment: Then you should manually iterate on the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` can help you get the job done.

Try:

```
...
} else if (args[i].startsWith("Body:")) { 
    body = StringUtils.join(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, i, args.length), " ")
                      .substring(5);
```